# Instance Binary of PSQueue

Tags: haskell

I have want to make a Binary instance for a Priority Sorted Queue from containers. I am using lts-7.0

If Test.hs is

```
import Data.Binary
import Data.PSQueue

instance Binary a => Binary (PSQ a Int)
```

running

```
stack ghci
:set -XFlexibleInstances
:load Test.hs
```

results in confusing error messages.

```
~> :load Test.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, interpreted )

Test.hs:4:10: warning: [-Wdeferred-type-errors]
    • Could not deduce (GHC.Generics.Generic (PSQ a Int))
        arising from a use of ‘binary-0.8.3.0:Data.Binary.Class.$dmput’
      from the context: Binary a
        bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:4:10-39
    • In the expression: binary-0.8.3.0:Data.Binary.Class.$dmput
      In an equation for ‘put’:
          put = binary-0.8.3.0:Data.Binary.Class.$dmput
      In the instance declaration for ‘Binary (PSQ a Int)’

Test.hs:4:10: warning: [-Wdeferred-type-errors]
    • Could not deduce (GHC.Generics.Generic (PSQ a Int))
        arising from a use of ‘binary-0.8.3.0:Data.Binary.Class.$dmget’
      from the context: Binary a
        bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:4:10-39
    • In the expression: binary-0.8.3.0:Data.Binary.Class.$dmget
      In an equation for ‘get’:
          get = binary-0.8.3.0:Data.Binary.Class.$dmget
      In the instance declaration for ‘Binary (PSQ a Int)’
Ok, modules loaded: Main
```

How can I get GHC to automatically derive the Binary instance of PSQ a Int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You unfortunately will need to actually write your own `Binary` instance for this. On the plus side, that is pretty easy in this case:

```
import Data.Binary (put, get)
import Data.PSQueue (toAscList, fromAscList, (:->))

instance (Binary a, Binary b, Ord a, Ord b) => Binary (PSQ a b) where
  put = put . fmap (\(k :-> v) -> (k,v)) . toAscList 
  get = fromAscList . fmap (\(k,v) -> k :-> v) <$> get
```

All this does is convert the priority queue to an ascending list of key-value tuples before/after converting it to/from binary.

### Why can't GHC do the work for me?

For GHC to work its magic of deriving the right `Binary` instance for you, it relies on a special class called [`Generic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Generic) that supplies high level information about the data contained in the different constructors. This class is derived (like `Read`, `Show`, `Eq`, etc.) with the [`DeriveGeneric`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XDeriveGeneric) flag enabled. However, since `PSQ` does *not* derive `Generic`, we might be stuck.

Normally though, there is another trick we can pull: enabling [`StandaloneDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#stand-alone-deriving-declarations) lets us derive as usual, but seperately from the `data` definition:

```
deriving instance (Generic (PSQ k v))
```

But that does require that the constructors of `PSQ k v` be public (which they are not in this case), so we really can do nothing to derive `Generic (PSQ k v)`. At this point, it is so much simpler to simply write the instance.

Comment: If you could derive `Generic` for an abstract type, you would be able to trivially break any abstraction barriers, so the compiler strictly prohibits it.